# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:52196/'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm trying to start selenium with firefox like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var driver = createFirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://duck.com");
    }

    IWebDriver createFirefoxDriver()
    {
        var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        service.FirefoxBinaryPath = BrowserPath.Firefox;
        var driver = new FirefoxDriver(service,
                                       new FirefoxOptions(),
                                       TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(80);
        return driver;
    }

public class BrowserPath
    {
        public static string? Firefox
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_firefox == null)
                {
                    m_firefox = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe", "", null) as string;
                }
                return m_firefox;
            }
        }

        private static string? m_firefox;
    }
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:53912/'
```

there's nothing on port 53912 as the command output nothing:

```
$ netstat -a -o | find "53912"
```

the `geckodriver.exe` is also in the output folder. How do I fix that?

Comment: Do you have anti-virus running? Maybe a firewall?

Comment: Which version of Firefox and GeckoDriver are you using?